# Terraform Azure Import Remote Backend to local State File

Tags: azure, terraform, github-actions

I have configured remote backend on my azure terraform .tf file. The remote backed file contains all the resources created - around 25 resources.

Now when I had to work on something new and did az login on VScode and did terraform init, the local state file doesn't look like the big remote state file. Hence the local terraform plan says it has to destroy all resources.

Anyone else faced similar issue?

How do I bring in the remote state back into my local vscode proj, so I can keep adding new changes?

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" { 
    resource_group_name  = "sandbox"
    storage_account_name = "d365fodev1sbfilesstg"
    container_name       = "terraform-state"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
   }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = true
}


# ############################ Storage Account ###########################
locals {
  storageAccount = fileexists("${var.storageAccountfilepath}/storageAccount.json") ? jsondecode(file("${var.storageAccountfilepath}/storageAccount.json")) : null
}

module "storageAccount" {
  source              = "./storageAccount"
  for_each            = { for element in coalesce(local.storageAccount, []) : element.name => element }
  storageAccountName  = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  filepath            = "${var.storageAccountfilepath}${each.value.name}"
}

############################ Function App ###########################
# locals {
#   storageAccount = fileexists("${var.storageAccountfilepath}/storageAccount.json") ? jsondecode(file("${var.storageAccountfilepath}/storageAccount.json")) : null
# }

module "functionApp" {
    # for_each     = { for element in coalesce(local.storageAccount,[]) : element.name => element }
    source = "./functionApp"
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Comment: Do you have the backend defined in your code? Can you add the relevant code to the question?

Comment: Hey @MarkoE, I have added the main.tf file above. You earlier suggestion on another post of mine worked, but now the local tfstate doesn't seem to be the same as the remote one which has all the resources defined.

Comment: If everything is configured properly, you shouldn't have a local terraform.tfstate file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to Azure Import Remote Backend to local State File using terraform and its works as per the plan stored in statefile remote repository.

Terraform's remote backend allows the state file to be stored in a shared location, such as an Azure Storage Account. This enables team members to access the same state and perform Terraform operations like `apply` and `plan` with the most recent state information. When you run `terraform plan`, Terraform compares your local configuration with the state file to determine the required changes. If your local configuration or state differs from the remote state, Terraform may mistakenly assume that resources need to be created, updated, or destroyed.

To sync your local environment with the remote state, make sure you have initialized Terraform with the right backend configuration. The command `terraform init` is essential, as it sets up your local Terraform to work with the remote backend. But, if there's a mismatch or an error in the command execution, it can cause the problems you're experiencing. Also, sometimes, forcing Terraform to reinitialize the backend can help. You can do this with `terraform init -reconfigure`. This makes Terraform reset the settings and pull the current state from the remote backend.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "demovk-rg"
    storage_account_name = "sampletextsavk"
    container_name       = "demosampletest"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "samplevkrg-test"
  location = "East US"
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "functionsapptestsavk"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azure-functions-test-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "testvk-azure-functions"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**terraform plan:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**terraform apply:**

[image]

now when I run the terraform code in local  VSCode importing the state file and made some changes related to version

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. I managed to resolve the issue. It is working now as expected.